# put some data on dashboard on real-time Power BI

Tags: business-intelligence, powerbi

Is there any way of Power BI allows me too show some data on real-time in a dashboard? Will I have to use the REST API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.  I you're using Azure Stream Analytics, you can create a real-time dashboard without needing to all the API Directly: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/

You can follow the instructions on this blog post to use the APIs to send data:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/archive/2014/12/23/power-bi-apis-real-time-example.aspx

There are several open source projects that show you how to push data to power bi, including one that has PowerShell modules that call into the API:
https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=powerbi

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But I cannot see this option

Click the job name.
Click Inputs from the top of the page, and then click Add Input. The dialog that opens will walk you through a number of steps to set up your input.

It only appeared region, storage, and something like that. I already tried to follow that tutorial.

Comment: Is your challenge now that you're having trouble getting ASA setup with an input?  Power BI is an output from ASA :) You'll need to send your data through an event hub and tell Azure Stream Analytics to output to Power BI.  Just a quick note on that: you need first to be a Power BI user (signup and sign-in at least once before trying). Here's another blog that might guide you as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/archive/2015/04/28/outputting-real-time-stream-analytics-data-to-a-power-bi-dashboard.aspx

Comment: thank you again. I'm only missing the first step when it says Data Services, I'll try again anyway.

Comment: @LukaszP. I was using Power BI API. But the problem with Power BI API is updating an existing row. There is now UPDATE command. And there is also no DELETE command for a specific row. You have to delete the whole table and insert all rows again, which is not possible with 0.5Mio rows. How is it with Azure Stream Analytics? Can you update a specific row?

Comment: No, stream analytics just uses the same REST API. It appends rows. We usually use Power BI Q&A to create tiles on top of that data using filters like "average in the last 30 seconds" which addresses the issue of seeing just latest data.